# Custom keyboard shortcuts not working for Excel contextual menu item

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

I want to bind control-option-command-F to "Filter by Selected Cell's Value", a contextual menu item in Excel. As you can see in the screenshot

[image]

it appears to be associated with the correct menu item, but pressing this keyboard shortcut does nothing. Selecting this menu item with the mouse does trigger the expected behavior.

I tried binding this same combination to a regular menu item ("Split") and that worked fine, so I don't think it's an issue of this combination of keys being incompatible with another shortcut.

Can anyone explain to me why this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Check your System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts.

It may be that those keystrokes are already bound to a System function.

Comment: As I said, I tried binding the exact same combination of keys to a different menu item ("Split") and it worked without any issue. So, this does not seem to be the problem.